# Reload a POST form with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dom-events, turbolinks-5

Here I have a problem with my search form.
When I submit my form, the search page load with my params, my PHP get my POST and display the reponse.

But, if I reload the search page, the browser doesn't give me an alert to reload the data, I know that turbolinks causing that, but I tried everything...

Conclusion :
When I submit, my POST (PHP) is not empty,
but after, when I reload, my POST doesn't exist anymore...

I tried : attr ==> data-turbolinks = false (to disable turbolinks on my search page)

How keeping my POST after a reload ?

NB : I don't use jQuery or any other library. Just Turbolinks.